# How do I check my SD Card file system type?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-sdcard, large-files

I'm trying to backup 4.5GB file to my SdCard. 
But my SdCard file system is FAT32, so that I cannot backup my file.
(FAT32 doesn't support to save 4GB size file)

File system limit - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

So I need to check my SdCard file system is FAT32 or not.
If my SdCard doesn't support to save large file then I need to save it by splitting.

Or if there is another way to check to save the large file?

Could you give me a help?

Comment: `my SdCard file system is FAT32` already provides an answer.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi yes, but i want to check other general cases. and i'll modify my question.

Comment: `i want to check other general cases` The filesystem never changes.

Comment: Java doesn't provide this facility in its native APIs. I suspect you'll have a hard time figuring this out in code.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I mean a case of using exFAT or FAT32 SdCard.
Some SdCard's file system is FAT32 but others are exFAT.

Comment: And some are ext4. So, your question should be: `How do I check my SD Card file system type?`

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried to investigate "mount" file but I couldn't get the information which I need. I think I need to study more...

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Thanks for your advice! I'll change my title immediately.